# Where is this water stream under the gutter coming from?

Tags: roofing, water-damage, gutters

I have a stream of water going under my siding from the gutters. The gutters are new and completely clean, no debris.  Also, the roof has vented drip edge extending into the gutters about an inch.

I can't see the water rolling over my gutter in the attached video.  What should I do to remediate this issue?  The water is getting behind my siding and causing damage to my bay window that is underneath.
[Video of water stream](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vkS6TcYlFxdN0JqeYpzYCZsj9hEVwZgw/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Did you see this question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18701/how-can-i-prevent-water-from-getting-behind-the-gutter?rq=1?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/170876/how-can-i-prevent-water-from-running-behind-my-gutters-and-under-shingles-near-a?rq=1

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/181733/water-dripping-from-soffit-problem-with-the-gutter-roof-or-something-else?rq=1

Comment: Thanks everyone, however this does no address my issue.  I had a adjuster review installation, drip edge and gutter at fault(installer says not his fault).  http://www.airvent.com/index.php/products/intake-vents/vented-drip-edge. Vented Drip edge installation guidance there.  If there is a way for water to wick its easy over all the drip edge vents, the final piece of the drip edge is tucked behind the gutter, as recommended in their installation instructions (why,  im not sure).  How do I tell if the water is going over the gutter or between the gutter and fascia?

Comment: Are you sure that water is getting behind the siding or is the water entering around the window trim? Looking at the video it doesn't seem likely that the water is going behind the gutter.

Comment: @Greg - there is no window trim where the bay window leak is.  It's siding and then bay window roof.  He leak is on the wall that the bay window juts out from.  The water looks like a stream to me and it is only occurring in that spot in the video.  Above it is a gutter and my main roof.

Comment: The only "stream" I see is on the outside surface of the siding. Any chance of posting pictures? It's quite difficult to guess and then have more details revealed through discussion. As it stands, there's not really enough detail to answer your question. Can you post pictures of the bay window and the siding around it? It the section of roof a valley where water comes together?

Comment: Is the downpipe at the end of the gutter (a) large enough and (b) not blocked?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody definitely made a big install mistake there... No quick fix for that it has to be all disassembled and put back together the proper way

Comment: But what is "the proper way"?